# Python: Django Requests

Tags: python, django, web-services, ubuntu

I am hosting Ubuntu on VMware Player, and I am working with Django using eclipse neon,Pydev, Anaconda3, it worked fine the request/response on the same machine(Ubuntu), but when sending a request from my windows to the hosted machine the following happens:
- Request sent successfully.
- No Response received.

Here is my code:

On Ubuntu:

-Django Code:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])   
def PredictLocations(request):

if request.method == 'GET':
    locations = Locations.objects.all()
    serilaizer = LocationSerializers(locations, many=True)
    return Response(serilaizer.data)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = LocationSerializers(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():


        return HttpResponse('Hey')
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

-Post Request:

```
import requests,json

url = 'http://localhost:8000/locations/'

payload = {"X": 1.0, "Y": 0.0, "Z": 10.0, "isSafe": 2}

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)
```

On Windows:

```
import requests,json

url = 'http://UbuntuIp:8000/locations/'

payload = {"X": 1.0, "Y": 0.0, "Z": 10.0, "isSafe": 2}

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)
```

What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Check your Django settings for `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Also, what's the status_code & reason you are receiving?

Comment: whats the output of print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)

Comment: No output ! the script just waits for the response ! But locally it worked.
I also tried setting ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] unfortunately no positive results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because you're using django's runserver, with default parameters. The problem is simple and simple to resolve: djangos runserver is binding to the loopback interface by default, not your LAN interface. It will only respond to requests originating from 127.0.0.1. But that's not a problem because `runserver` allows you to change interfaces and even the port if you want.

- Find the LAN ip of your ubuntu machine with `ifconfig -a` (let's pretend it's 192.168.1.10)
- Bind to it directly: `./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.10:8000`

Now you may need to change ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings, but for simplicity of development, just using the wildcard: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` is probably sufficient.

Comment: I did what you have said but no positive results bro!
- ifconfig -a = 192.168.37.138
- ./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.10:8000
- ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

I did all these steps ,but no answer from server!

Comment: That should be `./manage.py runserver 192.168.37.138:8000` then in your case. I was using `192.168.1.10` as an example, without knowing your actual LAN ip.

Comment: Also, quick side note, I'm assuming here that you correctly configured the VM network. I'd prefer a `bridge mode` connection, making your VM look just like any other node on your LAN.

Comment: Yes bro of course ! ./manage.py runserver 192.168.37.138:8000 , but it didn't work!

Comment: W.r.t the connections, I tried both, and I turned off firewall, but no positive results

Comment: From your windows Host machine, can you even ping the VM? Is your Host machine on the same LAN, 192.168.37.xxx?

Comment: This should work, for sure. Debugging backwards step by step: double check that the IP is correct in `http://UbuntuIp`. From the Ubuntu VM, attempt the same test (to itself, from itself, but over the LAN ip and not the 127.0.0.1). Finally, try connecting straight to 192.168.37.138:8000 from some other low level client (netcat, telnet, ..) just to see if the connection works that far. I'm all out of ideas, tbh. My only guess now is that it's a silly typo somewhere.

Comment: okay bro I will check everything you said from start, thanks anws

Comment: No results bro I tried everything from start :(, thanks anw